# DbContext - Ignore DbUpdateException and continue

Tags: entity-framework-4, ravendb, dbcontext

I need to write an application that migrates data from a RavnDB to SQL. 
I am pulling the data out of the ravenDB while it is still receiving lots of writes. This means that i am usually pulling stale data. 
On the SQL end i have a able with a primary key which is actually the GUID ID generated by the raven. Since i am pulling stale data - sometimes the same entities return. That's fine, however since i am working over EF when attempting to savechanges i get some DbUpdateException. 
So I was wondering if there is a way to tell DbContext to ignore DbUpdateException and continue inserting ?

Any ideas or comments would be very welcome,
Thanks

Comment: Can you not just catch the exception and eat it?

Comment: thx bob,
thats what im doing at the moment, however that seems like quite an expensive thing to do - there must be some way to override savechanges to achieve this - no ? 

thx again

Comment: On the EF side, I don't know if there is a setting for that. Another option is to cache your GUIDs in memory and do not insert if you've already added that GUID (GUID exists in your cache).

Comment: Yeh, but if i want to have many of these migrators running it introduces a lot of complexity which i was hoping to avoid. Really surprised that this isn't really simple to do.

Thank you again !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First i must say there is something fishy in your solution(ignore errors is bad practice in general) - maybe you should consider redesigning your solution.
Anyway if you do need to use Entity Framework there is an option to set custom stored procedure for your CRUD actions read about it [in this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321)
you can create SP for the insert:

```
 INSERT INTO tragetTable
 SELECT @id,@val1,@Val2
 WHERE @Id NOT IN(select id from tragetTable)
```

this may do the trick
good luck